# Json.simple спарсить array

Tags: java, json

Здравствуйте.

С сервера получаю json ответ вида:

```
[{"password":"xxxxxxx"}]
```

Как с помощью json simple можно получить значение `password`'a?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Получаете `JSONArray` с заданным ключом;
2. Получаете нужный элемент `JSONArray` по индексу.

---

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
try {
    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) parser.parse("{\"items\":[\"password\",\"xxxxxxx\"]}");
    JSONArray items = (JSONArray) object.get("items");
    System.out.println(items.get(1));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```